# Can I force hyperref to use a custom driver?

Tags: hyperref

As part of a [project to get LaTeX to output something useful](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/getting-latex-on-to-the-web/), I found myself wanting to write a new [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) driver for the desired format.  The documentation explains what a driver needs to do, but it doesn't explain how to get hyperref to load the new driver instead of its given one.  Looking through the code, I can't see an obvious hook but I may well be missing something.  At the moment, I load the driver file using the `\AtBeginDocument` hook, but it worries me that this might not be very robust.

So, can I get hyperref to load a custom driver *without* modifying `hyperref.sty`?  If not, are there any dangers from manually loading it myself at the start of the actual document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got [notified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59362/hyperref-link-placement-alignment-to-left-page-border-and-top-of-page/64829#comment157951_64829) about this thread and have now added option `customdriver` in
`hyperref` [6.83f](ftp://download.gnu.org.ua/pub/release/hyperref/hyperref-6.83f.tds.zip). From its `README`:

> ```
> Option `customdriver'
> ---------------------
>   The value of option `customdriver' is the name of an external
>   driver file without extension `.def'. The file must have
>   \ProvidesFile with a version date and number that match the
>   date and number of `hyperref', otherwise a warning is given.
>
>   Because the interface, what needs to be defined in the driver,
>   is not well defined and quite messy, the option is mainly intended
>   to ease developing, testing, debugging the driver part.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `hyperref.cfg` with the line `\def\Hy@driver{myhdriver}`. This will load a `myhdriver.def`. But it will work only with LaTeX (means dvi output) and not with pdfLaTeX (pdf output). With pdfoutput `hyperref` will force the use of the `hpdftex.def`.

Comment: Sadly, I do want PDF output; unless there's a `dvitotext` program that no-one's been tell me about.  (Yes, I know I _could_ do `latex -> dvi -> pdf -> text` but that seems a little ridiculous, plus I was hoping for a robust solution that didn't rely on a specific engine.)

Comment: Just a thought ... would it be possible to trick `hyperref` in to thinking it was being run by latex and not pdflatex?

Comment: Well you could perhaps set `\pdfoutput=1` only at `\begin{document}`. But I would at first ask Heiko. Perhaps he is willing to implement an option `specialdriver=....`.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, email Heiko (ideally with a patch attached!). He is usually very responsive about such things.

Comment: @Andrew: dvitotext is a FAQ :) http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fmtconv+toascii Check out `dvi2tty`, `crudetype`, `catdvi`

Comment: @Lev: Interesting read (particularly the nationality of the author of l2a!).  Thanks.

Comment: @Ulrike: I might just do that ... when I a working patch.

Comment: ... or when Bruno writes one!

Answer (score 3):

The patch below seems to do the trick. Declare the option `customdriver` to store its key in `\HyOpt@CustomDriver`. If that's nonempty then clobber `\Hy@driver` just before loading the driver file. *EDIT: added context for the diff, as requested by Andrew Stacey.*

```
*** hyperref-original.sty
--- hyperref-modified.sty
***************
*** 2861,2866 ****
--- 2861,2870 ----
      }%
    \fi
  }
+ \let\HyOpt@CustomDriver\ltx@empty
+ \define@key{Hyp}{customdriver}{%
+   \def\HyOpt@CustomDriver{#1}%
+ }
  \define@key{Hyp}{hyperfigures}[true]{%
    \Hy@boolkey[hyperfigures]{figures}{#1}%
  }
***************
*** 4206,4211 ****
--- 4210,4219 ----
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
+   \ifx\HyOpt@CustomDriver\ltx@empty
+   \else
+     \let\Hy@driver\HyOpt@CustomDriver
+   \fi
    \Hy@Message{Driver\HyOpt@DriverType: \Hy@driver}%
    \chardef\Hy@VersionChecked=0 %
    \input{\Hy@driver.def}%
```

Used as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[customdriver={foo}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
   \href{foo}{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice.  Okay, so next question is what is Heiko's email address?

Comment: @Andrew you can find the address on the `comp.text.tex` newsgroup. Or you can simply post it on `c.t.t.` directly.

Comment: To make this answer most useful, you should make that a _context_ or _unified_ diff.  I just blindly applied it against hyperref.sty from TL2010 and it was off by one line!

Comment: I don't know what a context diff is, sorry :(. And indeed, my patch is against TL 2011. I've got to leave for a week, btw.

Comment: Okey-dokey.  I might update your post to a context diff (it's sort of what it says: it adds a little context around the changes so that if lines get a bit offset then it's still easy to see where the changes should be applied.  If you're on a unix system, then you can produce them with `diff -c` instead of `diff`)

Comment: @Andrew: thanks for `-c`. I've added the context.

Comment: My apologies.  You've lost your "checkmark".  I hope you won't feel *too* sad.

Comment: No worry @AndrewStacey.  Obviously, Heiko's answer is better.