# Set header and footer rule color in memoir

Tags: header-footer, color, memoir

Is there a way to set color for header and footer rule in `memoir` class?

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % Allows the definition of hex colors

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{    \stretch{1}}
   \hfill    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.66    \textwidth}
   \raggedright
}%
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{    \stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}


\setlength{    \topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{    \textheight}{520pt}


\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule {myruled}{    \textwidth}{    \normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule {myruled}{    \textwidth}{    \normalrulethickness}{    \footruleskip}
\makeevenhead {myruled}{}{    \small    \itshape    \leftmark} {}
\makeoddhead {myruled}{}{    \small    \itshape    \rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot {myruled}{    \small      \thepage}{}{} 
\makeoddfoot {myruled}{}{} {    \small      \thepage}
\makeatletter % because of     \@chapapp
\makepsmarks {myruled}{
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark {chapter} {both} {nonumber}{    \@chapapp    \ }{.     \ }
\createmark {section} {right}{shownumber}{} {.     \ }
\createmark {subsection} {right}{shownumber}{} {.     \ }
\createmark {subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{} {.     \ }
\createplainmark {toc} {both} {    \contentsname}
\createplainmark {lof} {both} {    \listfigurename}
\createplainmark {lot} {both} {    \listtablename}
\createplainmark {bib} {both} {    \bibname}
\createplainmark {index} {both} {    \indexname}
\createplainmark {glossary} {both} {    \glossaryname}
}
\makeatother
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}


\begin{dedication}
Put dedication here
\end{dedication}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\pagestyle{myruled}

\chapter{Lipsum chapter}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

After loading `xcolor` packages I tried using `\color{colorname}` command but while it works for text it won't work when put before or after `\makeheadrule` or `\makefootrule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\makeheadfootruleprefix{<style>}{<for headrule>}{<for footrule>}
```

An example:

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % Allows the definition of hex colors

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
}%
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{520pt}

\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadfootruleprefix{myruled}{\color{Bittersweet}}{\color{PineGreen}}
\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead{myruled}{}{\small\itshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{myruled}{}{\small\itshape\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{\normalcolor\small\thepage}{}{} 
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{\normalcolor\small\thepage}
\makeatletter % because of \@chapapp
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\begin{dedication}
Put dedication here
\end{dedication}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\pagestyle{myruled}

\chapter{Lipsum chapter}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `\normalcolor` inside `\makeevenfood` and `\makeoddfoot` to prevent the page number to also receive color (remove `\normalcolor` of you want the number to be also colorized).

An image of one of the pages obtained:

[image]

Comment: Just tried your code but latex gives  "                   !Undefined control sequence.
l.33 \makeheadfootruleprefix
                            {myruled}{\color{red}}{\color{blue}}"

Comment: @Gianluigi update your LaTeX system, or (at least) the memoir bundle.

Comment: @Gianluigi works fine for me. Maybe its just an update needed.

Comment: I have Texlive 2012 but it seems that memoir.cls is an old 2009 version, will try to update and see if it works.

Comment: @Gianluigi OK; in my system (TeX Live2012) I have   `memoir.cls    2011/03/06 v3.6j configurable book, report, article document class`

Comment: @Gianluigi seems strange that you have TeX Live2012 and a very old version of memoir. Check if you're not using an old version saved in a local directory instead of the version from the LaTeX system.

Comment: I will try to reinstall it, i first installed TexLive 2012 from Ubuntu repositories, maybe a manual install will work better.

Comment: Reinstalled TexLive after removing original install and it works.(seems that Ubuntu 12.04 comes with TexLive 2009 preinstalled and even if i installed 2012 version it still called the old one)