# Memoir: Change color of header rule when using a copied pagestyle

Tags: header-footer, memoir, rules

Using memoir class, I am trying to change the color of the header's rule as proposed in [Set header and footer rule color in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74095/set-header-and-footer-rule-color-in-memoir). However, the following code won't change the rule's color:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\copypagestyle{mystyle}{ruled}

\makeheadfootruleprefix{mystyle}{\color{Bittersweet}}{\color{PineGreen}}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
foo
\end{document
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add

```
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
```

Also, the colors you are using are defined by `xcolor` loaded with the `dvipsnames` option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\copypagestyle{mystyle}{ruled}

\makeheadfootruleprefix{mystyle}{\color{Bittersweet}}{\color{PineGreen}}
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
foo
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, now I know why. When we copy the copied rule refers to the prefix used by the `ruled` style. Thus `\makeheadfootruleprefix` does nothing as the header refers to `\ruledheadruleprefix`.

Comment: I've added it to my TODO list to see if it can be solved. Otherwise I'll just add a caveat to the manual.

Comment: @daleif Good. Indeed it shouldn't be necessary to add that line.

Comment: @karlkoeller, in this case it might. I might need to patch macros instead of just copying them. Have to test if memoirs own system can do this, I'd rather not want to make it depend on things like `xpatch`.

Comment: This is been fixed in the next `memoir` release. Had to move the prefixes out or the rule commands in order to get `\copypagestyle` to work correctly.