# Add a figure on even page before chapter starts

Tags: chapters

I'm trying to do something very specific and I'm not able to find it on StackOverflow.
I'm building a novel, I've set all my chapters, and they always start on the odd numbered pages: PERFECT! That's what we all want I guess.
I would like to keep that logic, but also add another one that would put a given image on the page before (in front, the even numbered page). In my case that would be an illustration for the chapter. I don't want it to be part of the previous chapter and damage the display. I want it to be part of this chapter but always be on the front page of a starting chapter.

Does it make sense ? Am I trying to go too deep with LaTex ?

My code is very simple at the moment :

```
\chapter{Introduction}
Vous êtes-vous déjà demandé comment fonctionnait l’amour ? Est-ce quelque chose qui répond à une logique implacable ? Est-ce quelque chose que l’on peut prédire ?
Tout aussi certain qu’un verre d’eau se transformera en glace au congélateur, peut-on dire avec certitude qu’untel va rencontrer l’amour et vivre heureux ? Ou, au contraire, peut-on dire que sa vie sentimentale sera vouée à un chaos inéluctable, enchainant déceptions et solitude ?
\chapter{Suite}
Malheureusement, ce grand naïf qui vivait en dedans, j’ai dû l’étouffer pour aller de l’avant, pour m’émanciper dans ce monde en mouvement. Il me rendait faible, je devais être fort. C’est en tout cas ce que je croyais, à tort.
```

It is important for me to keep the initial logic, because let's say I have a chapter finishing page 48.
I want page 49 to be blank, page 50 to have a given image and page 51 to start the nex chapter

Thyanks in advance !

Comment: This implies the prvious chaper ends on an odd page, if I understand well!chapters begin  on an odd page, and have an illustration on the facing even page. Is my description correct?

Comment: that is how knuth's "texbook" is arranged, and it's very effective.  of course, that wasn't prepared with latex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simplest way is to have

```
\cleartoevenpage
\includegraphics{chapter pic}
\chapter{chapter title}
```

where `\cleartoevenpage` is like `\cleardoublepage` but always forces even rather than odd, it's defined in loads of places for example the `nextpage` package has a definition.

Comment: You're right, that's simple and that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!