# Obtaining the number of pages of a PDF included via \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

Background: I want a way to obtain the number of pages of the PDF that
is included using `\includepdf` (from the `pdfpages` package). To be
clear, I mean the PDF consisting of the (possibly proper) subset of
the pages of the original PDF that is passed as an argument to
`\includepdf`. E.g. if a 10 page document is an argument to
`\includepdf`, and only three pages are selected, I want the value
three.

The reason for this, is that I want to programmatically add a blank
page at the end of an document with an odd number of pages, but not to
the end of a document with an even number of pages.  So I technically
only need to know whether the number is even or odd, not the actual
number.

See MWE below. I have called the hypothetical macro that contains the
number of pages `\numberofpages`.

Since TeX has effectively global scope, I'm assuming that the macro
will return the number of pages corresponding to the most recent
invocation of `\includepdf`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\def\Filename{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\def\numberofpages{}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={2-4, 6}]{\Filename}
\numberofpages % 4
\includepdf[pages={4-6}]{\Filename}
\numberofpages % 3
```

Comment: probably pdfpages has this number but don't you know this in advance, you know the first is 4 and the  second is 2 (or there is an error)

Comment: why do you need to know the number of pages included? don't you just want to know whether the current page number after the inclusion is even or odd? (\ifodd\count0 ...`

Comment: Isn't something like `\clearpage\ifodd\value{page}\else\null\clearpage\fi` enough?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, the current page number after the inclusion would work too.

Comment: @campa Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate? Or just produce a complete example?

Comment: That line of code will conditionally add a blank page at the end of the document such that the document contains an even number of pages.

Comment: @campa Well, I need it after every invocation of `\includepdf`, to optionally add a blank page after each inclusion. Would that work?

Comment: but the current page number is just the current page number the fact that you use `\includpdf` on a previous page is not relevant.

Comment: I suggest this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248829/1090 (and others)