# Chapter's first figure on even page before chapter heading

Tags: floats, koma-script, chapters

I have several chapters that end on odd pages and would like to fill the following even page with a figure giving a graphical overview of the next chapter's contents. This figure should be correctly numbered as the following chapter's first figure.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,blindtext}
\usepackage{nextpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[b!]% float specifier only used so that first chapter ends on odd page
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This figure belongs to chapter~1. Should be numbered as Figure~1.1.}
\end{figure}

\cleartoevenpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\stepcounter{chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This figure gives a graphical overview of chapter~2. Should be numbered as Figure~2.1.}
\end{figure}

\cleardoublepage
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\stepcounter{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is another figure, should be numbered as Figure~2.2.}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

As you can see, example-image-b starts on the odd page left of chapter 2's heading. That's the way I want it to look.

However, this messes up the spacing in the list of figures as Figure 2.1 is listed along with Figure 1.1 and the inter-chapter spacing comes afterwards.
[image]

Since my approach is a big hack, there surely is a better approach I don't know about. Any help is appreciated.

Note that my current hack fails if the preceding chapter doesn't end on an odd page, but this limitation is acceptable in my case.

This is no duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248826/) since I want to have a correctly numbered figure and not just `\includegraphics` some illustration on the even page.

Comment: Maybe you need to redefine the `\chapter` command.

Comment: It seems strange to me that some chapters will be preceeded by a figure on the previous even page giving an overview of the chapter whereas some will not be preceeded by an overview. I think it would be consistent (and better) if either all chapters or no chapters were preceeded by an overview.

Comment: That's a valid point. However, I think in my case this inconsistency is justified (at least I hope so).

Answer (score 2):

This is a manual solution that preserves your code as much as possible. First we add the extra vertical space (10pt) before the figure 2.1:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%<<<
    \caption{This figure gives a graphical overview of chapter~2. Should be numbered as Figure~2.1.}
\end{figure}
```

Then we delete the same amount before the figure 2.2:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{-10pt}}%<<<
    \caption{This is another figure, should be numbered as Figure~2.2.}
\end{figure}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,blindtext}
\usepackage{nextpage}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[b!]% float specifier only used so that first chapter ends on odd page
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This figure belongs to chapter~1. Should be numbered as Figure~1.1.}
\end{figure}

\cleartoevenpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\stepcounter{chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
    \caption{This figure gives a graphical overview of chapter~2. Should be numbered as Figure~2.1.}
\end{figure}

\cleardoublepage
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\stepcounter{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{-10pt}}
    \caption{This is another figure, should be numbered as Figure~2.2.}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems even more hacky than my initial MWE, but if no one else has a better idea, I'll accept this answer in a few days. I think I'd switch to koma-script's `\@chapterlistsgap` instead of hardcoding 10pt.